# Remote ssh configuration problem

Tags: ssh, remote-access

My basic problem is that I would like to launch graphical application (eg firefox) on a remote computer (at work) from my computer at home. The computer at work (**WPC**) is behind a firewall. So I'm using SSH to remotely connect to it, in text mode.

The actual configuration I use is the following :

I have the Linux PC at work **WPC**
I have a network drive at home **NWD**
I have my Linux PC at home **HPC**

On **WPC**, I launch " ssh -R 23000:localhost:22 user@**NWD** "

When I am at home, I first connect from **HPC** to **NWD** via ssh : "ssh user@**NWD**", and then, from **NWD** to **WPC** via "ssh -p 23000 localhost"

That is working perfectly, but there is no X server on the network drive (**NWD**). So I cannot cascade two ssh -X connection.

Thus, I was thinking that I may connect directly from **HPC** to the 23000 port of **NWD** ? like that (from **HPC**) "ssh -X -p 23000 user@**NWD**", but then i got a connection refused.

The first question is do you think this could work (without an X server on **NWD**) ?

and if yes, How do I configure the sshd on **NWD** to allow access on port 23000 to other computers than just itself ?

Hope it is not too confuse

Thanks for your help

Julien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the explanation of `-R` in `ssh(1)` suggests, on **NWD** set `GatewayPorts yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Then connect with:

```
ssh -R 192.168.0.1:23000:localhost:22 user@NWD
```

where `192.168.0.1` is **NWD**'s local ip address. That should allow you to do

```
ssh -X -p 23000 192.168.0.1
```

from any of the computers on that subnet.

Comment: I forgot to thank you, it works perfectly now !